# Невозможно создать папку в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день.
Когда я создаю папку в Android Studio (например в директории res), она почему-то не появляется. Но когда захожу в папку проекта через "Мой компьютер", там она есть. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас включено отображение "android", при котором ресурсы определенным образом группируются. Переключитесь, например, на "project" (обведено красным вверху слева).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]